# Processing multiple csv files at a path in specific order

Tags: filenames, csv

I have 4 csv files at a location with the filenames containing the keywords-- Host,database,schema,table.

ex-

```
file_1_host
file_2_database
```

Now i want to perform some command on the data on these files in sequence of Table, Schema, Database and Host.

The logic i am thinking of is like below:

```
for csvfile in $CSV_PATH/*.[Cc][Ss][Vv]; do

        filename="$(basename "$csvfile")"
        if [[ "${filename,,}" = *table* ]]; then
    ./itres.sh delete record
fi
if [[ "${filename,,}" = *schema* ]]; then
./itres.sh delete record
fi
```

Just wanted to know, if another loop is required here to read the contents of each file?

Further detail:

Main command which i want to execute is `./itres.sh delete record <<input_file>.`
Input file can be of host, database, table or schema.

I want identify the file based on the file pattern first which has those host, tables ,database and schema keyword.
and then i want to perform the delete operation on the records inside the file.
The delete op will be same as the command mentioned above.

Comment: You can remove the shortest suffix matching `_thing` using POSIX shell substitution `${filename%_*}` ... if that's what you're asking

Comment: What is it you actually want to do with the files?  Without knowing, we can't tell if your approach is good or bad.  Do you need to process files in a specific order? Why?

Comment: Do those file names differ just in the keywords, or in the "prefix" (file[12]), too?

Comment: @markgraf-- I want to delete the assets which are there in the files. Like its an IBM Infosphere Governance Catalog process which has some cli level commands. I want to fire those command line scripts for each of those records in 4 different files. But host i have to run at last because a host has some databases and tables and it can't be deleted until the tables and databases and schema under that host is del;eted.

Comment: @steeldriver- sorry if my requirement is not clear..i will update it now.

Comment: Is my requirement clear?